# D-pad navigation - data structure and programming?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-tv, d-pad

I am tasked with implementing [d-pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-pad) navigation for an existing web application for GoogleTV (and I'm testing in Google Chrome, and so far they seem to operate similarly. [In their notes](http://code.google.com/tv/web/docs/implement_for_tv.html#dpadnavbasic) for implementing d-pad navigation they have basic handlers for up, right, left, down and select.

At present I have a scheme to initialize a virtual cursor, and then for the various dpad strokes. I rely on using [`document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) and looping through until I find a new element that was not previously selected. I'm using `outline:` css to indicate current position and I only show it when one of the dpad controls has been selected.

I have a step on initialization which adds the class `dpadClickable` to all the items which are clickable, and then as the cursor moves I have `dpadHighlighted` added to the new one and removed from all other elements. It looks right.

This all fails if I have an element which is scrollable, or if the orientation is such that moving my point downward finds nothing.

What I would like is a data structure to keep all my `dpadClickable` items in, and then on d-pad clicks, be able to iterate it to find the best closest top, down, left, and right elements. Like, should I do it based on the `top` and `left` properties? Or based on a calculated center point?

I found a [jQuery library](http://mike-hostetler.com/jquery-keyboard-navigation-plugin) which sort of implements this, and am reverse-engineering it to some extent. But what I'd really like is a primer on this class of programming problem: should I be looking for graphics programming algorithms? games? Something else?

[image: Page layout with blue boxes indicated selectable areas]

**UPDATE:** Question over on the [User Experience StackExchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) site: [Adding D-pad navigation to an existing web application: Resources?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10970/adding-d-pad-navigation-to-an-existing-web-application-resources)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at http://code.google.com/tv/web/lib/ where the official Google TV Java Script extensions / libraries are?  They might help you with this.

Comment: http://gtv-ui-lib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery/source/js/keycontrol.js appears to  have an interesting approach. It seems to break up the UI into zones and rows, and then you can navigate across these. Helpful!